# How to get rid of the line on top of every point on a line chart (Chart.js)

Tags: chart.js, linegraph

I'm working with Chart.js and creating line charts. I can't seem to get rid of the line above every chart coordinate. See the picture below. Which setting do I need to change to get rid of them? Thanks.

[Click me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10KYc.png)

Here is what the chart variable looks like

```
var chart = new Chart(chartx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
      data: data,
      fill: false,
      borderColor: 'rgb(0,0,0)', 
      borderWidth: 1,
      lineTension: 0,
      pointStyle: 'dash'
    }]
  },
        options: {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: true,
    animation: false, 
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    display: false
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    display: false
                }]
    },
            legend: {
                display: false,
            }
    },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you put `pointStyle: 'dash'` in your dataset attributes.

See [Chart.js doc](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart-data-structure) about LineChart data structure (`pointStyle` *is at the last row of the table*) :

> The style of point. Options are 'circle', 'triangle', 'rect', 'rectRot', 'cross', 'crossRot', 'star', 'line', and 'dash'. If the option is an image, that image is drawn on the canvas using drawImage.

You have to choose between the different options.

---

Note that there is no `none` option.

If you want to remove the point style, you can :

- Set the `pointRadius` attribute of your dataset to 0 (like in [this fiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/Lvdjx4c2/).
- Import an image as stated in the second part of the blockquote, which is empty (like [this one](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6c/Img_blank.png)).